# Select value and assign it to variable

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
$parentId = select id from node where uin_title = 'Control';
insert into list (id) values ($parentId)
```

I want to do this in oracle. Select 1 value from table node, assign it to a variable, and insert the variable in another table. I am not sure how to do it in oracle.

Answer (score 1):

The [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/apps/search/search.jsp?category=database&q=&product=) is a good place to start.

If you need to insert a single value, you can use a scalar variable:

```
declare
    v number;
begin
    select val into v
    from someTable
    where val != 999;
    --
    insert into someOtherTable(someField) values (v);
end;
```

This will not work if you have to insert more than one row; in this case, you need to use a collection:

```
declare
    type tableOfNumber is table of number index by pls_integer; 
    v tableOfNumber;
begin  
    select val
    bulk collect into v
    from someTable
    where val != 999;    
    --
    forall i in v.first .. v.last
      insert into someOtherTable(someField) values (v(i));
end;
/
```

The best way, however, is to use plain SQL, which is more readable and faster than PL/SQL ways:

```
insert into someOtherTable (someField)
  select val
  from someTable
  where val != 999;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with statement :

```
insert into list (id) select id from node where uin_title = 'Control'
```